# Re-structure the data of the MongoDB $lookup Query.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I want this to be the result
help me, thank you

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b74f57d3eb9591fcc069406"),
    "received_by" : ObjectId("5b6bac617e9f754ff8aebd65"),
    "received_date" : "2019",
    "code" : "TRSV16081800007",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "m_souvenir_id" : ObjectId("5b70e98ccb72df3bec00c94a"),
            "qty" : "10"
        },
         {
            "m_souvenir_id" : ObjectId("5b70e98ccb72df3bec00c94a"),
            "qty" : "10"
        },
        
        
    ]
}
```

the result is like this

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b74f57d3eb9591fcc069406"),
    "received_by" : ObjectId("5b6bac617e9f754ff8aebd65"),
    "received_date" : "2019",
    "code" : "TRSV16081800007",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "m_souvenir_id" : ObjectId("5b70e98ccb72df3bec00c94a"),
            "qty" : "10"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b74f57d3eb9591fcc069406"),
    "received_by" : ObjectId("5b6bac617e9f754ff8aebd65"),
    "received_date" : "2019",
    "code" : "TRSV16081800007",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "m_souvenir_id" : ObjectId("5b70e9d7cb72df3bec00c94b"),
            "qty" : "20"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a project with nosql in mongodb
I have a problem with nosql in mongodb, I've tried searching in various sources, but the results are still not what I wantI have a project like this in mongodb,

```js
db.t_souvenir.aggregate([
 { $lookup: { from: "t_souvenir_item", localField:"_id", foreignField:"t_souvenir_id", as: "Items"}},
        { $unwind : "$Items" },
 { $project : {
     "code":1,
     "received_by":1,
     "received_date":1,
                        items : {
     "m_souvenir_id":"$Items.m_souvenir_id",
                        "qty":"$Items.qty",
                        },
     
 }};**strong text**

]);
```

Comment: Please edit the title to describe your problem, not your project.

Comment: Try this `{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "received_by": { "$first": "$received_by" },
  "received_date": { "$first": "$received_date" },
  "code": { "$first": "$code" },
  "items": { "$push": "$items" }
}}`